# How to reset network manager

Tags: network-manager

I'm using Mobile Broadband using a nokia mobile to connect to Internet. All I did in my Ubuntu 12.10 is add 'new mobile broadband' (in terms of networking, no other tweaks).
**Problem:**
Yesterday i just test connected a *micromax* mobile (Not deteced by nm). After that i can't connect to internet using my nokia mobile. This is first in my experience (Connecting a phone make the network manager to not detect other one). `lsusb` and `ifconfig -a` show my phone without any problem. Then I connected the nokia to a live system, everything is OK until i connect the Micromax phone. (just phically. nm not even detected the micromax).After that no detection by nm.
I think reseting network manager will fix the problem.

Answer (score 95):

You can restart `network-manager` by doing (in the terminal):

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Certainly I find this can help with some network hardware issues (`network-manager` seems not to properly detect when my wifi is turned back on with an external switch, for instance), whether it will help here you will have to find out.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @chronitis, if your machine faces this problem more often, then you can create an alias in your UNIX based machine like `reset-wifi`. This will save your good mood and time.

```
$ echo "alias reset-wifi='sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

> This works for my machine: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Make sure you open new instance(new tab) of the terminal Emulator to check if the alias works.

Now everytime, you can reset using a single command.

```
john@john-Inspiron-7347 ~> reset-wifi 
  [sudo] password for john: 
  [ ok ] Restarting network-manager (via systemctl): network-manager.service.
```

Comment: In 2021 almost nobody uses init.d, so that will not work