# WiFi Dropout On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS dual boot Windows Surface Book

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, surface

I’ve been having issues where my WiFi connection initially works when I restart my computer and boot into my Ubuntu partition, but after a random amount of time anywhere from 1-10 minutes, my connection no longer works. No amount of deleting, manually re-adding the connection solves the problem. The only way I’ve been able to resolve this is by removing the connection, restarting the computer, and re-establishing the connection. This is great and all, but having to restart my computer ever 5 minutes or so isn’t exactly a productive use of time.

I’ve tried browsing some other similar questions on here and tried a few solutions, but have yet to come up with something that works for my situation. I don’t believe it has to do with the drivers, as I can establish a connection, but it’s inconsostent and drops out. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I’m able to connect to Internet via Bluetooth (using my phone as a personal hotspot connected to our home WiFi) but it’s not a permanent solution...

Comment: Have you tried [restarting network manger](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251913/how-to-reset-network-manager). Not a fix but might help.